# Filter Finder Items

Tags: macos

How can I get Automator to exclude Folders or Aliases from "Get folder contents" results in OSX 10.5.8? the "Filter Finder Items" action doesn't have either of these options. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At least the Automator in 10.8 supports excluding both types of files. For file types that don't have extensions, you can select "other" and type the localized description as a kind.

[image]